# Kendo UI - Date Picker - Max Val

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, datepicker, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using Kendo's datepicker, and I need to set a max-date of 2 week / 14 days from current date.

Here is the Kendo datepicker, I know the max value is incorrect, just trying to illustrate what I am looking to do:

```
           @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                    .Name("EventEndDate")
                    .Value(DateTime.Now)
                    .Min(DateTime.Now)
                     .Max(DateTime.2WeeksFromNow) // This nees to be 14 days from current
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:150px" })
                )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This razor code will give you the date 14 days from when the page is rendered.

```
 .Max(DateTime.Now.AddDays(14))
```

If you need a floating max date you will need to either force a refresh or use JS to change the max date.
Here is an example with JavaScript.

```
var Date = new Date();
Date.setDate(Date.getDate() + 14);

$("#EventEndDate").data("kendoDateTimePicker").max(Date);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi can you not just do this:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                    .Name("EventEndDate")
                    .Value(DateTime.Now)
                    .Min(DateTime.Now)
                     .Max(DateTime.Today.AddDays(14)) // This needs to be 14 days from current
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:150px" })
                )
```

This should add 14 days for you.

Comment: This is working for me. One thing to suggest is make sure you include the appropriate culture script so the control can interpret the datetime correctly. I am using the en-GB script.